# event not trigger on first click parent Childs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, checkboxlist

I am creating hierarchy relations list with parent Childs and sub-childs if i checked parent then all Childs with checked but i clicked on Childs then sub-childs will be checked. everything is working fine but its work on second click not working on first click.
here is my fiddle example.
fiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/fahadsheikh/qdkwy0s7/8/

```js
function changeCategoryStatus(_this, id) {

var main = document.querySelector(".main-checkbox"+id);
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-checkbox"+id);

function toggleCheck() {

  var array=[];
  children.forEach(child => {
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        child.checked = child.checked = true
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        child.checked = child.checked = false
    }

    
    array.push(child.value);
    
  })

  return array;
}

if(main){
    main.addEventListener("click", toggleCheck);
}

//for sub-parent category

var sub_parent = document.querySelector(".sub-parent"+id);
var sub_children = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-checkbox"+id);

function toggleCheck() {

  var array=[];
  sub_children.forEach(child => {
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        child.checked = child.checked = true
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        child.checked = child.checked = false
    }

    
    array.push(child.value);
    
  })

  return array;
}

if(sub_parent){
    sub_parent.addEventListener("click", toggleCheck);
}

 
    var status = $(_this).prop('checked') == true ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"{{url('admin/categories-status')}}",
        data: {
            id: id,
            status: status,
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        success: function (result) {
        $("#status-success").show();
        $("#status-success").html(result.success);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#status-success").hide()
        }, 3000);
        }
    });

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortable">
   <div class="group-caption">
       <li class="main-parent category-sortable main-item" data-parent="4" data-position="4" data-newposition="1">second room 
                <span class="buttons-align">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input class="main-checkbox4" type="checkbox" id="user-4"
                        onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 4);"
                        >
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
                
                </span>
                <div class="move" id="item-move" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
                <ul class="group-items group-items-parent">
                                                                                <li class="group-item-parent category-sortable" data-parent="5" data-position="1" data-newposition="1">second-child room 
                    <span class="buttons-align">
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input class="sub-checkbox4 sub-parent4" type="checkbox" id="user-5"
                            onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 5);"
                            >
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    </span>
                    <div class="move"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>

                                                                                <ul class="group-items-child">
                                                                    <li class="group-item-child category-sortable" data-parent="6" data-position="1" data-newposition="0">second subchild
                                    <span class="buttons-align">
                                    <label class="switch">
                                        <input class="sub-checkbox4" type="checkbox" id="user-6"
                                            onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 6);"
                                            >
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="move"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                                            </ul>
                </div>
                                                                                <div class="group-caption">
                <li class="main-parent category-sortable main-item" data-parent="7" data-position="4" data-newposition="2">third-room 
                <span class="buttons-align">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input class="main-checkbox7" type="checkbox" id="user-7"
                        onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 7);"
                        >
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
                
                </span>
                <div class="move" id="item-move" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
                <ul class="group-items group-items-parent">
                                                                                <li class="group-item-parent category-sortable" data-parent="9" data-position="1" data-newposition="1">third-child 
                    <span class="buttons-align">
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input class="sub-checkbox7 sub-parent7" type="checkbox" id="user-9"
                            onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 9);"
                            >
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    </span>
                    <div class="move"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>

                                                                                <ul class="group-items-child">
                                                                    <li class="group-item-child category-sortable" data-parent="10" data-position="1" data-newposition="0">third-subchild
                                    <span class="buttons-align">
                                    <label class="switch">
                                        <input class="sub-checkbox7" type="checkbox" id="user-10"
                                            onclick="changeCategoryStatus(event.target, 10);"
                                            >
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="move"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></li>
                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                                                            </ul>
                </div>
                                                                
            </div>
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your current logic is that you are attaching the `toggleCheck()` function to the main checkbox *every time the checkbox is clicked*. This causes the odd behaviour you see.

Also note that your HTML is invalid. `li` elements must be children of the `ul` only, not `div`, and the `ul` itself cannot be a child of another `ul`. You need to structure your nested lists correctly. You can also improve the HTML by removing the incremental id and class attributes. They are an anti-pattern which leads to more complex code than necessary. Use DOM traversal to relate elements instead.

Regarding the JS code, you should avoid the use of the inline `onclick` event handlers as they are no longer good practice. Use unobtrusive event handlers added via your JS logic. Also you're redefining the `toggleCheck()` function numerous times, which is a big code smell.

With all that said, the HTML and JS can be massively simplified:

```js
$('.sortable :checkbox').on('change', e => {
  let $cb = $(e.target);
  let isChecked = $cb.prop('checked');
  $cb.closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', isChecked);

  /* 
  // AJAX commented out for this demo only  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{url('admin/categories-status')}}",
    data: {
      id: $cb.prop('id'),
      status: isChecked ? 'active' : 'inactive',
      _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#status-success").html(result.success).show();
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#status-success").hide();
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
  */
});
```

```css
body {
  /* background-color: #20262E; */
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.move {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div class="sortable">
  <ul class="group-caption">
    <li class="main-parent category-sortable main-item" data-parent="4" data-position="4" data-newposition="1">
      second room
      <span class="buttons-align">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </span>
      <div class="move">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="group-items group-items-parent">
        <li class="group-item-parent category-sortable" data-parent="5" data-position="1" data-newposition="1">
          second-child room
          <span class="buttons-align">
            <label class="switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="5" />
              <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
          </span>
          <div class="move">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="group-items-child">
            <li class="group-item-child category-sortable" data-parent="6" data-position="1" data-newposition="0">
              second subchild
              <span class="buttons-align">
                <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="6" />
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
              </span>
              <div class="move"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="group-caption">
    <li class="main-parent category-sortable main-item" data-parent="7" data-position="4" data-newposition="2">
      third-room
      <span class="buttons-align">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="7" />
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </span>
      <div class="move">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="group-items group-items-parent">
        <li class="group-item-parent category-sortable" data-parent="9" data-position="1" data-newposition="1">
          third-child
          <span class="buttons-align">
            <label class="switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="9" />
              <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
          </span>
          <div class="move">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="group-items-child">
            <li class="group-item-child category-sortable" data-parent="10" data-position="1" data-newposition="0">
              third-subchild
              <span class="buttons-align">
                <label class="switch"> 
                  <input type="checkbox" id="10" />
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
              </span>
              <div class="move">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```